# Simplify templating query with Super Table

Tags: plugin-supertable

The following code will return the correct result, but since I'm quite new with Craft, I wanted to know if there was a more preferred/efficient way to filter this in the template (or maybe create a custom function).  Here we go:

```
{% set currentDay = now|date('l') %}
{% set currentTime = now|date('H:i') %}
{% set entries = craft.categories.group('shows') %}

{% for entry in entries %}
  {% for row in entry.showschedule %}
    {% for day in row.airingDatesEn %}
      {% if day == currentDay|lower %}
        <li>{{ entry.title }}</li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

As you can see I'm looping over all the `entries` in the craft category 'shows', then looping over the SuperTable row `showschedule`, then looping over the checkbox category `airingdatesEn` to see if it contains the current day.

Seems like I'm doing a lot of barrel rolls here, any ideas on how to simplify?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Someone else will surely better answer the larger question you're asking, but one small point: as you've written it, you're running the filter `currentDay|lower` many, many times.

Since that will be static for the duration of the loop, even if Craft/twig doesn't have more efficient ways to handle your query, you should do something like `{% set currentDayLower = currentDay|lower %}` once around line 4 and then compare `{% if day == currentDayLower %}` in order to avoid re-doing a filter in a loop.